# Get next post when using pagination with WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, pages, pagination

How do i specify which "page" to get when using WP_Query? I'm using pagination and i only display three posts per page, but i need to manually set which page to get, because Wordpress doesn't do that by default it seems.

Is there an argument i can send with `WP_Query()` to get a specific page?

Answer (score -1):

before WP_Query() check page condition is_page('pade_id') 
if true then execute the wp_query().

Comment: No, sorry, i don't want to specify the page id, i want to specify the current pagination-page. Let's say i'm browsing my blog frontpage which lists 10 posts per page. If i click "next page" at the bottom, it will (should) show me the next 10 posts. That would be "page" 2 of the frontpage. Do you get what i mean?

Comment: In in which file u are using pagination in single.php or page.php ???? Currently what is happening ???

Comment: If u want only 3 post per page then use argument post_per_page=3  in wp_query().

Comment: The loop that gets post is in a file called loop.php, which i just include on my pages where i want to display posts. I know i can use `posts_per_page`, but that will only limit the post count, it's pretty much the same as using `numberposts`. I need to get the posts from a different page using an argument. Do you understand? This is kinda hard to explain...

Comment: Either that or an argument that functions as an "offset". So if i use 2 as offset, it will give me X posts starting from 3 (excluding the first two). That would also work.

Comment: ...and i just realized that `offset` exists. That'll work. :) **Edit:** To be more clear, what i actually did was: 1) Grab the current "page" from the url by parsing it out from the url.  2) Get the default posts_per_page option value. 3) Calculate the offset, something like: `$currPage < 2 ? 0 : ($cp*$posts_per_page)-$posts_per_page`. 4) Send that into the WP_Query in the `offset` argument.

Comment: Really its very hard to understand for me how you want your post on your page  "I need to get the posts from a different page using an argument.  See the link pagination by post category work on server not at localhost "http://w3grip.com/wordpress/list-category-posts-with-pagination-plugin/"

Comment: you can call specific category post using  wp_query or exclude that category.

Comment: i think you are not getting next 10 posts when next link is clicked